# Calculus Proving

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = e^x(1-x)$.

Use Mean Value Theorem to show that for any $x$ in $(0,1)$, there is an $a$ in $(0,x)$, such that

$e^x(1-x) = 1 - a x e^a$

Deduce that for any (0,1),

$e^x(1-x) < 1$.

What i have done

Let f(x) = $e^x(1-x)$ for x in (0,1)
Then f is cont on [0,1] and differentiable on (0,1)

MVT => There exists an $a$ in (0,1) such that f(1)-f(0) = f '(a)

-1 = - $a$  $e^a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the mean value theorem to $[0,x]$ instead of $[0,1]$. Note that $f$ is differentiable on $[0,x]$, hence there is an $a \in (0,x)$ such that 
$$ f(x) - f(0) = (x-0) \cdot f'(a) \iff e^x(1-x) - 1 = -axe^a $$ 
Hence $e^x(1-x) = 1 - axe^a$.

Comment: it should be $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ in the LHS and hence the $x$ in the RHS.

Comment: @Samrat Upps ... thx.

Comment: For deducing that for any (0,1), $e^x(1−x)$<1. 


$axe^a$ will always be positive.

So 1-$axe^a$ < 1 for (0,1)


So $e^x(1-x) <1